# Android: how to animate viewstub?

Tags: android, animation, view, viewstub

How to inflate view with some animation?

Answer (score 7):

First call the `inflate()` method, then setup an animation on the returned view, like this:

```
View view = ((ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub_view)).inflate();
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.makeInAnimation(this, true);
animation.setDuration(300);
view.startAnimation(animation);
```